# Not understanding how to initialize pointers for source/sink class logic

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, initialization

After changing my source output to a pointer, I started getting segfaults happening on calls to my `GetOutput()` function. I'm fairly certain I'm not initializing `output` correctly. Initializing it to `NULL` as I'm currently doing doesn't work, and I'm fairly certain it doesn't make sense either considering it would mean that `output` would never hold anything. It's also possible I'm just making a syntax mistake, I suppose. So I'd appreciate any ideas as to how I should initialize my `output`.

```
// source.c
#include <iostream>
#include <source.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

Source::Source()
{
    Image * output = NULL;
    output->SetSource(this);
}

Source::~Source() {}

Image * Source::GetOutput() const
{
    std::cerr << "This function never executes due to segfault." << std::endl;

    output->ResetSize(output->GetWidth(), output->GetHeight());
    return output;
}

void Source::Update()
{
    Execute();
}


// source.h
#include <image.h>

#ifndef SOURCE_H
#define SOURCE_H

class Image;

class Source
{
    public:
        Source();
        virtual ~Source();
        Image * GetOutput(void) const;
        virtual void Execute()=0;
        virtual void Update();
    protected:
        Image* output;
};

#endif
```

Comment: You need to allocate memory manually using `new` if you want to use a pointer. I'm not sure using pointers here is a good idea tho, a standard variable should do, unless you're deriving from `Image`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try working with `new`. Some of the recent changes I made did involve making `source` be derived from `Image`, which it originally wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code first sets the pointer to `NULL` and then tries to use it, so of course there's an error.

```
Image * output = NULL;
output->SetSource(this);
```

Instead, you can initialise it by using the `new` keyword, like so:

```
Image *output = new Image;
output->SetSource(this);
```